# A devine / appréhende / perçoit ce qui me passe par la tête

Tags: sens, verbes

Bonjour,

> A **devine** ce qui me passe par la tête.
>
> A **appréhende** ce qui me passe par la tête.
>
> A **perçoit** ce qui me passe par la tête.

Est-ce que tous les trois verbes sont possibles dans cette phrase ?

Comment: Tout est possible mais c'est à toi de donner le contexte qui entoure la phrase.

Comment: @None Bien sûr, mais je voulais juste voir que tous ces verbes étaient possibles ici, je n'étais pas sûr de "percevoir".

Answer (score 2):

Les trois sont des possibilités, la première étant courante. Le troisième, le plus difficile à justifier à cause de son sens majeur de  prendre connaissance par les sens  ([TLFi, **I A**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/percevoir)) a  cependant aussi le sens  « prendre connaissance par l'entendement » ([**I B**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/percevoir)) ; même si ce verbe est bien moins souvent utilisé avec ce dernier sens il n'y a aucun doute que l'on peut s'en servir avec « passer par la tête » puisque ce qui passe par la tête de quelqu'un ne peut être saisi que par des déductions logiques àp d'échange verbal ou de la logique de certaines actions (sans échange verbal) ; même si ce qui se passe dans la tête de quelqu'un   transparait seulement dans des attitudes sans échange verbal et n'est en fin de compte manifesté que par les sens (ouïe, vision, toucher), un raisonnement est nécessaire et il est  fondé sur ces manifestations. Ça n'a pas à être quelque chose de compliqué ; par exemple, d'un simle air renfrogné, on déduit immédiatement
qu'une attitude négative est la réaction ; c'est un processus de l'intelligence et non  sensoriel.